# In java language, how to convert nano seconds value, for example 1568694302232954486 and 1568703521360049938 into a Java Date object?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, logstash-file

I have many long numbers which look like 1568694302232954486 and 1568703521360049938, and I need to convert each of them into a Java Date object.

How to implement the above requirement in Java 8?
I also need transform the nanosecond value into elasticsearch's timestamp and have found the correct way; thanks for all the help!

Just for those who need it, the following code block has passed the test. It's actually part of a logstash configuration file:

```
ruby {
            init => ""
            code => "
            event.set('time_local',event.get('time_local').to_f*0.000001)
            "
        }

        date {
                #15/Aug/2019:14:46:19 +0800 [02/Sep/2019:09:28:33 +0800]
            match => [ "time_local" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS","UNIX_MS"]
            timezone => "Asia/Shanghai"
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
```

Comment: What is the expected result ? `Tue Sep 17 04:25:02 GMT 2019` for `1568694302232954486`?

Comment: Note that `Date` is obsolete, although you may encounter older libraries that use it.

Comment: Do you mean an `Instant` object?   If you're after a `Date`, then you're not using Java 8.

Comment: Ruby convertion code segment which outputs date format string like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss is also acceptable.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson yes, Tue Sep 17 04:25:02 GMT 2019 is ok, thank you and what the code snippet is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

It’s very easy when you know how. While the second parameter of the two-arg `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` is named `nanoAdjustment`, it has type `long`, and the method accepts the full nano value being passed in this parameter. So just pass 0 as the seconds and leave the conversion to the method:

```
    Instant instant1 = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, 1_568_694_302_232_954_486L);
    System.out.println(instant1);
    Instant instant2 = Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, 1_568_703_521_360_049_938L);
    System.out.println(instant2);
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2019-09-17T04:25:02.232954486Z
> 2019-09-17T06:58:41.360049938Z
> ```

If you do need an old-fashioned `Date` object for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to upgrade just now:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate1 = Date.from(instant1);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate1);
```

On my computer the converted `Date` was printed as:

> ```
> Tue Sep 17 06:25:02 CEST 2019
> ```

Generally do avoid the `Date` class, though. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Working with java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as a `Date` object, then you are going to lose some information, because `Date` only has millisecond precision. `Date` is also obsolete in Java 8, so if you are using Java 8 or above, consider using `Instant` instead.

Here is how to convert to `Date`. Don't do this unless you *really* have to.

```
long nano = 1568694302232954486L;
Date d = new Date(nano / 1000000); // 1000000 is how many nanoseconds there are in a millisecond
```

`Instant` on the other hand has nanosecond precision, and is what you should be doing:

```
// 1000000000 is how many nanoseconds there are in a second.
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochSecond(nano / 1000000000, nano % 1000000000);
```